# a property is not defined ejs: nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I was following a tutorial and got stuck here. Everything looks ok to me. Still I am getting this error. Can some one point me to the right direction.

> memberName is not defined

```
    <% for(var i=0; i < notes.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="list-group-item">
          <div>Note from <em><strong><%=memberName[i]%></strong></em> on:
            <%= createdOn.toDateString() %>
              <strong><%= project[i] %></strong></div>
          <div><strong>Work yesterday:</strong>
            <%= workYesterday[i] %>
          </div>
          <div><strong>Work today:</strong>
            <%= workToday[i] %>
          </div>
          <div><strong>Impediment:</strong>
            <%= impediment[i] %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <%}%>
```

Controller code:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    var query = Standup.find();
    query.limit(12)
        .exec(function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            res.render('index', { title: 'Standup - List', notes: results });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%=memberName[i]%>` in the ejs file mean "when I ll send the ejs, I ll replace that by the value of memberName".

But in your controller, you don t provide it, which block ejs.

In the controller, you should have something like:

```
res.render('index', {
    title: 'Standup - List',
    notes: results,
    memberName: memberName //<--
});
```

When this one will be fixed, you ll also have to provide `createdOn`, `project`, `workYesterday`, `workToday`, `workTomorrow` and `impediment`.

Answer (score 0):

`<%=` is a EJS tag for evaluating values in HTML.
`<%= memberName %>` will output the value of variable `memberName` in your HTML code. Thus you need to pass the parameter memberName while you are rendering the html page. You have missed out the parameter.
Your controller code should look like:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    var query = Standup.find();
    query.limit(12)
        .exec(function (err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            res.render('index', { title: 'Standup - List', notes: results, memberName: 'Test Member Name' });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < notes.length; i++) { %>
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <div>Note from <em><strong><%= notes[i].memberName %></strong></em> on:
      <%= notes[i].createdOn.toDateString() %>
        <strong><%= notes[i].project %></strong></div>
    <div><strong>Work yesterday:</strong>
      <%= notes[i].workYesterday %>
    </div>
    <div><strong>Work today:</strong>
      <%= notes[i].workToday %>
    </div>
    <div><strong>Impediment:</strong>
      <%= notes[i].impediment %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <%}%>
```

Which can be further reduced to this:

```
<% notes.forEach(function(note) { %>
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <div>Note from <em><strong><%= note.memberName %></strong></em> on:
      <%= note.createdOn.toDateString() %>
        <strong><%= note.project %></strong></div>
    <div><strong>Work yesterday:</strong>
      <%= note.workYesterday %>
    </div>
    <div><strong>Work today:</strong>
      <%= note.workToday %>
    </div>
    <div><strong>Impediment:</strong>
      <%= note.impediment %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% }) %>
```